# multiple y-axis values for single date on x-axis - google visualzation api

Tags: java, javascript, google-visualization

I need to draw a chart based on some values given.

This is how my data looks like...
(Date on xAxis and Values on yAxis)

```
|| Date       || X1 || X2 || X3 ||
|| 01-01-2008 ||  1 ||  2 ||  3 ||
|| 01-01-2008 ||  2 ||  3 ||  4 ||
|| 01-02-2008 ||  1 ||  2 ||  3 ||
|| 01-03-2008 ||  1 ||  2 ||  3 ||
|| 01-04-2008 ||  1 ||  2 ||  3 ||
```

So now in the graph i need to get a straight vertical line for first two values plotted.

But the line chart from visualization api is showing two separate columns for first two date values...

i.e.,

```
xAxis - Jan 01, 2008 || Jan 01, 2008 || Feb 01, 2008 || Mar 01, 2008 || Apr01, 2008
```

instead of

```
xAxis - Jan 01, 2008 || Feb 01, 2008 || Mar 01, 2008 || Apr01, 2008
```

and plotting a vertical straight line for Jan 01, 2008

```
the graph should have vertical straight line for Jan 01, 2008 without omitting the     duplicate values...
so that the two values that are against Jan 01, 2008 are displayed vertically
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Set collections for storing the values, A set is a  collection that contains no duplicate elements. So once you store "Jan 01,2008", it will not allow duplicates.

use any implementation class of Set,

```
//create a hashset
HashSet<String> xAxis = new HashSet<String>();

//and store values like this

xAxis.add(date1)
xAxis.add(date2)
```

here im assuming you are storing String values, but you can change it according to your need.

Comment: by doing so i loose some values ...
i need to show a vertical line in the chart for the xAxis value...

Comment: But according to your question, you said you are getting duplicates and wanted to get rid of them, please clarify/edit your question and also supply some code.

Comment: sorry for the confusion... i have added a line that it shud show a vertical straight line for Jan 01, 2008 to avoid dat confusion.